# Create new object from an existing one

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities, Participante and Emitente. The Emitente extends the Participante.

For example:

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(true)
@Default
@Table(name = "participantes")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Participante implements IEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "codigo", nullable = true, length = 20)
    private String codigo;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Cacheable(true)
@Any
@Table(name = "emitentes")
public class Emitente extends Participante {

     //other methods and properties

}
```

In my application I have two screens entries, registering just one for the Participantes and one for registering the Emitentes. 
The problem is that in some cases I need to create a new Emitente from a Participante that already exists.

For example: I signed a Participante, saved in the database and everything, I decided that there is an Emitente. Then I go on the Emitente screen and pull the Participante to it, add the other properties relating to the Emitente and click on save.

is there a way to do this automatically or do I have to set property for property manually in the database?

Or rather, Hibernate can do this for me?

If someone can not understand me know that I try to explain better.

Thanks to all and sorry for my English is not the best!

---

To better explain I created this sample application can be downloaded at the following link:
[Aplicaçao](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2mw7Hlip92vTGIwU3FoYTFUZDg/edit?usp=sharing)

To run it just use NetBeans and create a MySql DB with the name "testeHeranca", this way is better explain.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Added link to the sample application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a few forums in Brazilian sites and I concluded that I shall change my estratédia entities!

Thinking that the JPA works with a limited kind of polymorphism, it would be like changing the type of the object.

In this specific situation, a viable alternative would be to change the type of inheritance relationship to aggregation, ie, where "Issuer" has an attribute of type "Participant". Thus the tables do not need to be changed and you can include entities separately at any time.

Follow the link StackOverflow in Portuguese.

[ps.stackoverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27916/hibernate-heran%C3%A7a/27929#27929)

I thank everyone who tried to help me!

Answer (score 0):

(sorry cannot comment yet)

You have to initialize Emitente. 
It's completely new entry in Emitente table.

In Emitente, just create a constructor which takes Participante object, and creates Emitente based on that.

Comment: ok, I do it. For exemple: Emitente emitente = new Emitente(participante).
But when I save it, I need to merge or persist Emitente?

Comment: At the moment I create it manually in the database. For example:. Sql = "INSERT INTO issuers (id, inc_trib_prev, ...) values ​​(emitente.getId (), ...)" getEntityManager () createNativeQuery (sql)
I do this because I have not got the Emitente registered in my database

Comment: The initial status - Participante is persisted, and no Emitente exist for that Participante. So we need to create a new Emitente, based on the existing Participante, and persist it.

Comment: It's just that way it is not working the way I want. I edited the question to add an example. If you can help thank you.